# Adding Commands Based off of Directories Found

Tags: bash

Is there a way to make a bash script which scans a directory `dir0` for folders, such that for all folders `dir1` which are found in `dir0` a command `dir1-command` is created with the following definition:

```
dir1-command() {
 cd dir0/dir1
 echo "inside dir0/dir1"
 cd -
}
```

**EDIT:** The specific problem I'm trying to solve is this: I have a folder called `scripts` which has subfolders like `scripts/haskell_script1` and `scripts/haskell_script2`. The way to launch, say, `scripts/haskell_script1` is as follows:

```
haskell_script1() {
 cd scripts/haskell_script1
 stack exec haskell_script1 -- $@
 cd -
}
```

And so what I'd like to do is, every time `~/.bashrc` is sourced, scan my `scripts` folder and generate a bunch of commands of form `haskell_scriptX` to save me time. That way I don't have to manually create a command for every haskell project/folder folder that I create.

Comment: What is the issue that you're trying to solve by this?

Comment: @Kusalananda: I provided more detail in my question above.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to make a function, `run_haskel`, that takes an argument and executes `( cd scripts/haskel_$arg && stack exec haskell_$arg )` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your .bashrc:

```
for script in scripts/haskell_script*
do
  # strip off the leading "scripts/" portion
  script=${script##*/}
  eval "function ${script} { 
    cd scripts/${script}
    stack exec ${script} -- \$@
    cd -
  }"
done
```

You have to be careful about anything inside that definition that might get prematurely `eval`uated, which is why I escaped the `$` in `$@`.